# Confusion about Android's onLayout Parameters

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I recently wrote a custom layout and came across a few issues. One of them I've solved was the onLayout Parameters left, top, right, and bottom but i don't exactly know why it works. I initially thought in order for me to position the children, i had to make the, for example, y-axis to be positioned between top and bottom parameter values while the x-axis to be positioned between the left and right values. After coding in that approach, i wrote the xml layout as following:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
 <com....customlayout>
  <ImageView />
  <ImageView />
 </com....customlayout>
  <com....customlayout>
  <ImageView />
  <ImageView />
 </com....customlayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

The issue i had was the second custom layout did not draw it's children. I looked through the onLayout code I wrote for the custom layout and I end up changing the following:

```
void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int leftPos = l;
    int topPos = t;
...
   dst.left = leftPos + child.getPaddingLeft();
   dst.right = leftPos + child.getMeasuredWidth();// pixels;
   dst.top = topPos + child.getPaddingTop();
   dst.bottom = topPos + child.getMeasuredHeight();// pixels; 

...
}
```

to

```
void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int leftPos = l;
    //int topPos = t;
...
   dst.left = leftPos + child.getPaddingLeft();
   dst.right = leftPos + child.getMeasuredWidth();// pixels;
   dst.top = /*topPos +*/child.getPaddingTop();
   dst.bottom = /*topPos +*/ child.getMeasuredHeight();// pixels; 

...
}
```

The second custom layout started to draw it's children. So my initial assumption was incorrect. I think I have to position the dst.left to be less than l parameter, dst.right to be less than r parameter and so on. My question is, why is that? Wouldn't I be placing the children to the top-left of the android screen (unless there are some type of translate calls behind the scene)?